# How to link a text area to a submit PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm having a little bit of an issue that I think is simple and I am missing something!

Techs in use: 
PHP, HTML, SMARTY, MYSQL, JQUERY, JAVASCRIPT

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

HTML:

```html
<form id="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  {LOOP}
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn verified" style="margin-right:20px; opacity:0.2;"><i class="icmn-radio-checked" style="font-size:10px;color:#01a4f8;"></i>
            <input type="radio" name="frm_verify[]" value="{$ID}" class="verified" ><br>Verified
          </label>
    <label class="btn active notverified" style="margin-right:20px;"><i class="icmn-radio-checked" style="font-size:10px;color:#01a4f8;"></i>
            <input type="radio" name="frm_verifyno[]" value="{$ID}" checked multiple class="notverified"><br>not Verified
          </label>
  </div>

  <textarea class="NOTES" name="verifyno_notes[]" class="form-control"></textarea>
  {LOOP}
</form>
```

From the above form I am (using PHP) trying to get the notes to correlate to a PHP function > MySQL storage. This form is LOOPED multiple times in output on page see {LOOP}

PHP:

```
if ( $_POST['submitit'] ) {
for ($x=0; $x<count($_POST['frm_verifyno']); $x++)
{
   $value = $_POST['frm_verifyno'][$x];

// get order details
$result         = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = '".$value."'");
$sDeviceinfo = $result->fetch_assoc();

$result         = $db->query("SELECT claimref FROM SECONDTABLE WHERE id = '".$sDeviceinfo['orderid']."'");
$sClaimref = $result->fetch_assoc();

$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $db->query("INSERT INTO
                  THIRDTABLE
                  SET
                  `state` = 'MISSING',
                  `notes` = 'MISSING',
                  `user` = '".addslashes($sAdminDetails['fname'] .' '. $sAdminDetails['lname'])."',
                  `ts` = NOW(),
                  `date` = NOW(),
                  `orderid` = '".addslashes($sDeviceinfo['orderid'])."',
                  `deviceid` = '".addslashes($sDeviceinfo['id'])."',
                  `imei` = '".addslashes($sDeviceinfo['imei'])."',
                  `serial` = '".addslashes($sDeviceinfo['serial'])."',
                  `claimref` = '".addslashes($sClaimref['claimref'])."',
                  `userip` = '".addslashes($userip)."'
                  ");
}
}
```

The above WORKS for the radio buttons.

So, my question is, how does one also link in the textareas into this?

I have tried (what i thought was) the same kind of process to get the input sent to PHP correctly so i 'know' which textarea correlates to which mysql row entry.

When this form runs it inserts multiple rows (as per count of the loop)

Comment: `$note= $_POST['verifyno_notes'][$x];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the fields are in the same loop, you can just do

```
$cnt = count($_POST['frm_verifyno']);
for ($x=0; $x<$cnt; $x++) {
   $value = $_POST['frm_verifyno'][$x];
   $note= $_POST['verifyno_notes'][$x];

.
.
.
```

Comment: Hi man, ty for your Answer it hhas been very helpful. Although I am having one issue with it. The PHP side of things, it is inserting all rows APART from the last one. well, it is inserting it but it is BLANK in any of the sDeviceinfo and sClaimref variables. Any idea what i need to do?

Comment: That is a separate PHP question